# How to get regular price of BUNDLE product

Tags: price, bundle-product

I have an bundle product like this:

```
Bundle product:
**Option 1:
-subproduct:15$
-subproduct:7$
**Option 2:
-subproduct:5$
-subproduct:20$
In admin of product page, i set Special Price 90%.
```

In category page, it's display:

```
Bundle product
As low as:
10.8$
```

How can i show regular price like this?

```
As low as:
Reg:12$  Spec:10.8$
```

Thanks for read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i find a answer, here my code:

```
$_product     = $this->getProduct();
$typeInstance = $_product->getTypeInstance(true);
$typeInstance->setStoreFilter($_product->getStoreId(), $_product);

$optionCollection = $typeInstance->getOptionsCollection($_product);

$selectionCollection = $typeInstance->getSelectionsCollection(
    $typeInstance->getOptionsIds($_product),
    $_product
);

$options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection, false,
    Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck()
);
$summin = 0;
$summax = 0;
foreach ($options as $option){
    $selections  = $option->getSelections();
    $minprice = array();
    foreach ($selections as $key => $_selection){
        $minprice[] = $_selection->getFinalPrice();
    }
    $summin += min($minprice);
    $summax += max($minprice);
}
```

$_minimalPriceBundle = $summin;
   $_maximalPriceBundle = $summax;

you can put code wherever you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be the active `price.phtml` template. Examine the section responsible for rendering the grouped product prices. Add in the necessary code to render the regular price.

Comment: hi @musicliftsme , how can i get regular price to show